# Probability of having 4 of 5 inside sample normal interval

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, standard-error, z-score

I need help with one question from one MOOC quiz I am currently doing.

## Question

Recall from an earlier question. Suppose that diastolic blood pressures (DBPs) for men aged 35-44 are normally distributed with a mean of 80 (mm Hg) and a standard deviation of 10. What's the probability that in a random sample of 5 subjects, 4 or more have DBPs more than 90?

### My Attempt

First step is to transform to a standard normal with the following:
$$
(90-80) /(10/\sqrt{5}) = 2.2361
$$

Looking 2.23 up at the z score table, I will find the value of 0.9871, thats the area of the left side of the Z-score, so the area to the right of the z score will be:
$$
1 - 0.9871 = 0.0129
$$

So my interpretation is that, I am confident that 1.29% of the data is concentrated at more than 90 DBPs. 
Is my reasoning correct until now?
The correct answer at the coursera quiz is 0.29% that I successfully deducted by being a very low percentage, but how do I get to that value?

Comment: A much higher proportion would be at 1SD or above than what you calculate. .You should be thinking of 90 mmHg as being 1 SD above the mean and looking up the probability of seeing an occurrence at that level or above from a Normal table or using your computer. There would be 5 ways to get exactly 4 observations like that, and one way to all five like that. I get a slightly lower estimate for the correct result (0.0028), but I suspect the difference is due to rounding error (theirs, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the transformation you applied should not have $\sqrt {5} $ - this is for a t-statistic for the sample mean.

You are basically dealing with a binomial distribution here. Consider the indicator variable $x_i=1$ if $z_i>90$ and $x_i=0$ otherwise. Then take the new variable $y=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5$. The question is then $Pr (y\geq4) $

I'll add more a a day or 2

Comment: This was really helpful along with @DWin comment. Since 90 was 1STD from the mean, doing the calculations, there was a 15.87% chance that someone was above that. So the binomial Pr(X >= 4) = 0.002786, rounding that to 0.0028, plus the Pr(X > 4) = 0.0001, gave me the answer of 0.29%. 

The only thing quite not clicking in my head, it's why should I discard the 5 subjects sample information, because of that I mistakenly calculated the 2STDs from the mean.